# Execute javascript function on tiny mice text are content

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have an issue with tiny mice,

Actually I am loading a html page where tiny mice is applied on a text area.

and I want to applied  javascript function to remove a class from text area content .
How can i do that.
Provide any suggestion please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tinyMCE.get('text_area_id').setContent('') 
 So what I'm suggesting is that you get the tinyMCE editor and then set the content to nothing in between the ('').  This should clear out the content, I tried it on my window

Comment: Thanks ! and let me try!